# UITableViewCell not getting updated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

For every entry in the table view cell, I need a button at right then some text and again a button at the left. At the button click event I need to change the text (left/right button clicked.) and remove either of the buttons depending on the text conditions. I am not able to remove the buttons using cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I tried subclassing the UITableViewCell and use method -prepareForReuse but I can't reset the cell. Any ideas how do I achieve this? Or is there some way to make this button invisible or may be hide?

```
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}


[self.tableView clearsContextBeforeDrawing];
NSString *str = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.text = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];       
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrow_Right.png"];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(290, 5, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        button.frame = frame;   
        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(rightArrow_clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:button];

        UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];      
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrow_Left.png"];
        CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(5, 5, img.size.width, img.size.height);
        button1.frame = frame1;
        [button1 setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(leftArrow_clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:button1];

    if([str isEqual:@" abc  "])
        [button setEnabled:NO];
    if([str isEqual:@" pqr "])
        [button1 setEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: Yes it is a reusable cell. How do I reset it in the -prepareForReuse method?

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do is subclass UITableViewCell, and add the subviews in the `init` method so that they're only added once.

What's most likely happening is you're adding subviews to a reusable cell, which most likely already has buttons on it from a previous use. In addition, you can set the buttons to "invisible" like so:

```
[button setHidden:YES];
```